# Why does this query fail?

Tags: php, jquery, psql

```
<?php

$connect = pg_connect("dbname=$dbase host=".$host." user=".$user." password=".$pass) or die("I sense a disturbance in the force ");

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch($action){
case 'bagSubmit' : bagSubmit(); break;
}

function bagSubmit(){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cntrt';
    $query = pg_query($connect,$sql) or die('could not connect');
}
?>
```

The above php returns 'could not connect'.  The sql query executes fine in the database.  This is my normal procedure for executing queries in php (always worked before).  The only difference now is that I am calling the php from jquery.  The jquery is executing fine as well, as evidenced by the fact that the query's failure ('could not connect') is returned.  What am I missing?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'functions.php',
data: {action: 'bagSubmit'},
type: 'post',
success: function(response){
    $('body').append(response);
}
});
```

Comment: Can we see how jQuery calls the php code?  Are you sure you're using `POST`?

Comment: He doesn't appear to be using any data that's being passed by jQuery other than conditionally sending the query, i doubt jQuery has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: Explosion, as requested, the jquery has been added to the post.  I don't think there's anything wrong with it, though since the query IS executing (but failing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    $host = "10.10.10.129";
    $user = "postgres";
    $pass = "";
    $dbase = "attest";
    $connect = pg_connect("dbname=$dbase host=".$host." user=".$user." password=".$pass) or die("I sense a disturbance in the force ");

    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch($action){
        case 'bagSubmit' : 
            bagSubmit($connect); 
            break;
    }

    function bagSubmit($connect){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cntrt';
        $query = pg_query($connect,$sql) or die('could not connect');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Haha I type too slow. `+1`

Comment: I gotta give it to Adeneo since technically he was a minute sooner.

Comment: Thanks, was actually typing it before I noticed Neal's comment, and I'm a slow typer too, so I'm not **that** fast, all though the ladies tell me otherwise ?

Answer (score 7):

$connect is not defined.
You need

```
function bagSubmit(){
    global $connect;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cntrt';
    $query = pg_query($connect,$sql) or die('could not connect');
}
```

Comment: Ehhh idk if the global is a good idea. Maybe just pass the connection to the function?

Comment: True! A better practice. Better than that... use a class :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using globals, just pass the `$connect` object to your function:

```
function bagSubmit($connect){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cntrt';
    $query = pg_query($connect,$sql) or die('could not connect');
}
```

And call it like so:

```
bagSubmit($connect);
```

Comment: Neal, your solution solved the problem.  I guess sometimes its the simple things that slip under the rader.  Thanks

Comment: No problem @MattWall Happy to help! ^_^